# XMLHttpRequest. Send data NOT in UTF-8. Is mission imposible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to send data  using XMLHttpRequest (method POST) to the server.

Conditions and restrictions:

1. The server always assumes, that  character encoding is windows-1251 only.
2. I can't change anything on the server's side. The server is not mine.
3. My code must work in FF, Chrome and IE8 :-(  I experimented with `sendAsBinary` but unsucessfully.

As I can see, XMLHttpRequest before sending always modifies data to UTF-8, thus problem can't be solved.
Right?

Comment: There is a not on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest

`Note: When sending a nsIDOMDocument, versions of Firefox prior to version 3 always send the request using UTF-8 encoding; Firefox 3 properly sends the document using the encoding specified by body.xmlEncoding, or UTF-8 if no encoding is specified.`

Answer (score 1):

You say "XMLHttpRequest before sending always modifies data to UTF-8."

THAT IS WRONG!!! XMLHttpRequest should be encoded before sending, the encoding is defined by document self.

for html5, you can use `<meta charset="YOUR-ENCODING-HERE">`.
for html or xhtml, you have to use 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=YOUR-ENCODING-HERE-WITHOUT-QUOTES">`.
for xml, you can use `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="YOUR-ENCODING-HERE"?>`.

then, before XMLHttpRequest.send(), you have to `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","SOME-OTHER-DECLARATION; charset=YOUR-ENCODING-HERE-WITHOUT-QUOTES");`.

Given all above, no matter what encoding your server defaultly assumes, it will using the charset the request suggests (if it supports) to decode the URI.

There is another way to do it.

I don't know what programming language used in your server side. For java, you can use, say `str` is the string the server got, `newStr = new String(str.getBytes("SERVER-ASSUMED-CHAR-ENCODING"), "YOUR-HTML-ENCODING");`

In your case, this would be `newStr = new String(str.getBytes("windows-1251"), "UTF-8");`.
And the newStr should be the readable data.